# How could it's be possible that under iOS 12 UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset is null?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, phasset

under iOS 12, in :

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<UIImagePickerControllerInfoKey, id> *)info;
```

I sometime receive error log saying that `UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset` inside `info` is not present. How this can be possible ? I also see that at the same time `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` is also absent !

NOTE: I show the imagePicker **ONLY** when `PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus` return `PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`

Answer (score -1):

some app users change new iPhone，or upgrade new system，some image or video is upload to iCloud，they may not download to local.
If they upload new avatar by using this image，may be log is the asset URL is nil，I met several times in my company 's app.